# Jenkins parameterized build not creating file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, filereader

Maybe I am misunderstanding the intended use for the Jenkins file parameter here...

I want to be able to upload a file containing some data (in my case comma separated variables). I then want to simply read this file and do stuff with the data. I've got this setup using a Pipeline job.

My file location is set to 'email_list.csv'. In my pipeline script I have

```
node {
  stage('post') {
    emailFile = readFile 'email_list.csv'
    println "${emailFile}"
    //.........
  }
}
```

This fails with a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/job-name/email_list.csv (No such file or directory)` exception

Shouldn't the parameterized build have set up this file? If not, how do I read the data uploaded?

Comment: I've noticed that this only happens when using a Pipeline job, not freestyle ones. Problem is I need a Pipeline job as I've found they're the only way of passing variables into a HTTP request body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Pipeline Job with file parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080876/jenkins-pipeline-job-with-file-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins by default provides build job parameters as a `params` map in pipeline. It is a key-value pair. All you comma seperated values will be into values field. You can refer them in your groovy script as,

`print params.emailFile`

To dump it as a file, you can use `writeFile` library function.

P.S: If you `print params` in groovy script, you will be able to see all build parameters of your job.

Answer (score 0):

There is a a bug since ages that makes impossible to use  `fileParameter`:

- [Handle file parameters](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27413)
- [file parameter not working in pipeline job](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47333)