# Jenkins File parameter hide/delete

Tags: jenkins

I have jenkins job to import ssl certificate; 
I am using file parameter to upload the certificate key file;

My job is working fine but under console output --> parameter, I could see the content of key file which I would like to hide considering a security risk.

Is there any way I can delete/hide the content of key file from parameter?

Under jenkins I am executing Job in the following way

> $ import_ssl.py -keyfile {key_file} -certfile {cert_file}

key_file and cert_file are file parameter.

I'm having limited control over jenkins(I am not admin);

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect your `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`.

> import_ssl.py -keyfile {key_file} -certfile {cert_file} > /dev/null 2>&1

After this you won't get any output in console. You can can just redirect `stdout` if that works. As I am not sure in case of error what happens.

> import_ssl.py -keyfile {key_file} -certfile {cert_file} > /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

Strange that you use File Parameter and yet worry about security in the console, but don't worry about file storage

Try InputFile:
[Jenkins Pipeline Job with file parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080876/jenkins-pipeline-job-with-file-parameter)

In conjunction with the other answer on hiding the output:
/dev/null 2>&1