# Jenkins pipline upload file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a jenkins pipeline with file upload parameter.
unlike regular job that uploads the file to the workspace, pipeline job seem to do nothing with the file I pick.

Do you know how I can use uploaded files?

from the UI - pipeline configurations:
[image]

from the UI when running the pipeline:
[image]

my pipeline script for example run 'ls' just to check if the file was uploaded:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
        
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Avi

Comment: I deleted my answer after your update on the question. I think your request is mostly similar with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080876/jenkins-pipeline-job-with-file-parameter